# Rerouting with Navigation UI SDK only works once

Tags: mapbox

Android API: all
Mapbox Navigation SDK version:0.42.6

Hello guys, I´m using a navigation view where I fetch the route using the function MapboxMapMatching, cuz I´m using a microservice where I calculate the route by my own, so I use MapboxMapMatching to fetch the points of my route. Then as im using Mapbox Navigation UI SDK, I use also the function "allowRerouteFrom" where i call again my microservice and fetch the route again using MapboxMapMatching and finally return false as the Mapbox documentation says (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/map-matching/#map-matching-with-navigationview).
Expected behavior

The user can be rerouted the times that he gets lost.
Actual behavior

The fonction allowReouteFrom only works once, I mean... I can be lost once and the app will reroute you based in you current location (that's great) but if I get lost another time, the application never enter again to allowRerouteFrom function to fetch the new route.

Here is my function "allorReroutFrom(){}" that I´m using to "attack" the user offroute problem:

```
>     @Override
>         public boolean allowRerouteFrom(Point offRoutePoint) {
>             navigationView.stopNavigation();//I do this, cuz if not, the listenner still continue working and the application crashes 
>            
>             //Route Request, Im using a microservice and doing the request with OkHttpClient
>     
>             OkHttpClient client= new OkHttpClient();
>             String url= ....
>     .....
>                     if (response.isSuccessful()){
>                         final String myResponse = response.body().string().trim();
>                         PruebaNavegacion.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                             @Override
>                             public void run() {
>                                 try {
>                                     JSONObject jsonObject= new ...
>     ...
>                                                 pointsrecalruta.add(Point.fromLngLat(Double.parseDouble(longitud),
> Double.parseDouble(latitud)));
//Here I read the points of the new route that i want follow
>      
>                                     }
>     //Then I use MapboxMapMatching function to fetch the  new route
>                                     
>             List<Point> pointsrutarecal = new ArrayList<>();
>                                     pointsrutarecal=pointsrecalruta.subList(0,pointsrecalruta.size()-1);
>                                     DirectionsRoute route = null;
>                                     //inicioArray=inicio;
>                                     //finArray=fin;
>                                     MapboxMapMatching.builder()
>                                             .accessToken(theMapboxToken)
>                                             .coordinates(pointsrutarecal)
>                                             .waypointIndices(0,pointsrutarecal.size()-1)
>                                             .steps(true)
>                                             .voiceUnits("metric")
>                                             .language("es")
>                                             .voiceInstructions(true)
>                                             .bannerInstructions(true)
>                                             .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)
>                                             .build()
>                                             .enqueueCall(new Callback<MapMatchingResponse>() {
>     
>                                                 @Override
>                                                 public void onResponse(Call<MapMatchingResponse> call,
> Response<MapMatchingResponse> response) {
>     
>                                                     if (response.isSuccessful()) {
>                                                         Log.i("Mapa","iEntre al reponse succesfull");
>                                                         if(response.code()==200) {
>                                                             Log.i("Mapa","iEntre al reponse succesfull,code 200");
>     
>                                                             try {
>                                                                 DirectionsRoute route =
> response.body().matchings().get(0).toDirectionRoute();
>     
>                                                                 // progressDialog.dismiss();
>                                                                 //rutarecal=route;
>                                                                 // Create new options with map matching response route
>     
>                                                                 NavigationViewOptions options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
>                                                                         //.routeListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         //.directionsRoute(route)
>                                                                         .navigationListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         .directionsRoute(route)
>                                                                         .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
>                                                                         .progressChangeListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         .instructionListListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         .speechAnnouncementListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         .routeListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                         .bannerInstructionsListener(PruebaNavegacion.this)
>                                                                 //setBottomSheetCallback(options);
>                                                                 //setupNightModeFab();
>                                                                         .build();
>                                                                 navigationView.startNavigation(options);
>     
>                                                             }catch (Exception e){
>                                                                 Toast.makeText(PruebaNavegacion.this, "Ruta invalida",
> Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     
>                                                             }
>                                                         }
>                                                         else {
>                                                             Log.i("Mapa","iEntre al reponse succesfull code no 200");
>                                                             Log.e("mapa","MapboxMapMatching failed with "+response.code());
>                                                         }
>                                                     }
>     
>                                                     else{
>                                                       //Anything happend here
>                                                     }
>                                                 }
>     
>                                                 @Override
>                                                 public void onFailure(Call<MapMatchingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
>                                                     Log.i("Mapa","iEntre al reponse failure");
>                                                     Log.e("Error mapa:", "MapboxMapMatching error"+throwable.toString());
>                                                 }
>                                             });
>     
>                                     //Fin del mapmatching
>     
>                                     //progressDialog.dismiss();
>                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
>                                     e.printStackTrace();
>                                 }
>     
>                                
>                             }
>                         });
>     
>                     }
>                 }
>             });
>         
>     // Ignore internal routing, allowing MapboxMapMatching call
>             return false;
>         }
```

Thank you for any help, if you have any question please ask me.

Gabriel.

Comment: It’s impossible to help you without seeing your relevant code.

Comment: Absoutely, you're right. I just modified the question an added the code of the function, if you need to see more parts of my code just tell. Thank you for any help.